# emailing a direct link to executable file blacklist risk

Tags: email

I hope this is in the right place, don't know where else to ask.

I would like to automatically send a download link to people that directly downloads an executable. The executable is a verified and safe file. People will request this email with the download link themselves. Will I risk compromising the integrity of the emailaddress im sending from by being blacklisted if I send such emails. If so would zipping the file be better? Or should I direct people to a web page where they need to click again to download the file?

I would like the download to be as hassle free as possible but also trustworthy to the people im sending it to. And off-course not risk being blocked by any spam filters of be blacklisted.

Answer (score 2):

From my personal experience it would be better do send a link to a webpage where the user has to download the software by cklicking on a download link/button. There are many spam/ malware filters for mail out there blocking mails with direct links to software.

I encountered this many times trying to get updates of our software to various clients. Now we made a downloadpage with doesn't include the strings '.exe', '.msi', '.zip' and many others. Since then we don't have problems with filters any more.

Also it offers another level on security because we have secured the downloadpage with  username and password, so if one of the emails is read by some third party they still can't simply download the software. But as I don't know exactly what you are trying to do, this may not apply to you.

Comment: No, this would work for me, but I was hoping sending direct link to users wouldn't be a problem. Since I want it to be as hassle free as possible. But this would be the best solution to make sure no problems arise I guess.